# How to block certain IP addresses on UEFI system?

Tags: ip, firewall, uefi, network-adapter

So I have several OS on my PC and I'm frequently changing this. Is there some way I can block certain IP address on my NIC so that I can't access it no-matter what.

I'm thinking maybe if there could be some UEFI low-level driver that could do that?

My NIC is 3com 3c905b-tx and my motherboard B75M-GL.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a such thing as a UEFI driver system like what you mention. Instead UEFI defines a series of standardized interfaces that devices need to conform to if they want to be accessible via UEFI without OS-level drivers.

For network stuff (such as a BIOS-based web browser), it's up to the manufacture of the motherboard or BIOS to implement such a thing.

Blocking IPs without a local firewall is something that routers (or some switches) are for. It appears that most routers these days support IP blocking, even [cheap ones](http://www.tp-link.us/products/details/cat-4762_TL-R402M.html).

Comment: This seems more like a comment then an answer.  It does not answer either question the author had.

Comment: @Ramhound It answers the title question. The second question isn't really a question. I'll see about updating my answer to be more direct.

Comment: The original revision was a single sentence.  The answer to this question requires more then a single sentence to answer in my opinion.  I should not have to ask for more information in my opinion.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think it does require more than a single sentence and no further information was necessary. While you may have found my original answer unsatisfactory in its level of detail, it did answer the question of how to block IPs without the usual software firewall. (The UEFI stuff would only have been relevant if it had been feasible to use that system to block IPs.)

Comment: I don't agree.  Which is the great thing about life, people have different opinions, my only goal is to see the highest quality content possible.